# The Greatest and the Least of These. code edited

Tags: java

I need to finish my assignment but I am stuck so weird place. I almost finish all codes but I have an issue on assigning small value.

- When I type -99 program stopped.  Perfect
- When I type strings try-catch works. Perfect
- when I type numbers max value shows. perfect

but when I type like number 5 15 26 68. Shows max number is 68. min number is 0.
I need to fix that issue but I could not.
Can you guys help me to fix it?

```
    String str; // to hold input string
    int a; // for convert string to int
    int max = 0; // max and min assigned to min/max values.
    int min = 0;


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Create a Scanner object to read input.
    boolean can = true; //boolean loop

    // Get the user's input.
    while (can) // input validation loop
    {

        try    
        {

            System.out.println("Enter an integer ( press -99 to quit)"); //direction to user.
            str = input.nextLine(); // get a string containing an int number
            str = str.trim(); // remove any extra whitespace from string sides
            a=Integer.parseInt(str); // convert. 


            if(a==-99)
            {
                System.out.println("The maximum is:'"+max+" and the minimum is: "+min+"'.");
                break;
            }


            if(a>max) // max and min number formulas
            {
                max=a;
            }


            if(a<min)
            {
                min=a;
            }       
        }

        catch (Exception e) // handle the exception below
        {
            System.out.println("INPUT ERROR: Please enter an integer number!!"); // output error
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()); // show what user did/wrote.

        }
    }
```

Comment: You should post your actual code, not a picture of your code. Also, I think it is time to learn how to debug.

Comment: Initialize `int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;`

Comment: Here's a hint - where do you set the min value?

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize `min` to  a big value, not to `0`.

Set it to the maximum value of `int` like this :

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Likewise, if your program accepts negative values, you'd better initialize `max` to the smallest possible integer (which is -2147483648), not to `0` :

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

Comment: min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; and int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
what if user type -99 and quit the program without any numbers?

Comment: Enter an integer ( press -99 to quit)
-99
The maximum is:'-2147483648 and the minimum is: 2147483647'.

Comment: Try to print this way : `System.out.println("The maximum is:'"+(max==Integer.MIN_VALUE?0:max)+" and the minimum is: "+(min==Integer.MAX_VALUE?0:min)+"'.");`

Comment: Thanks, Berger. Now it is working. I just started to learn on. hopefully I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem occurs because you set the min value as 0 at the start of the program. Therefore, the only numbers less than that value will be negative numbers. 5 is greater than 0.

The ideal way around this would be to use `int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE` which will initialise min to the maximum possible integer value. Therefore, all numbers should be less than or equal to that number, unless it's a larger size than can be stored in 4 bytes

As detailed by other answers, you should also consider setting `int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE`

Comment: I think you meant to say OP should initialize the `min` to the `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, otherwise nothing will be smaller than min and so you will still have the same issue.

Comment: That is correct. Editing now.

Answer (score 0):

The code `if(a<min) min =a;` never executes because always your `a` value is less than min.You should initialize min value to first value.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot everything is ok. The input sequence produces the right results:

```
start    max = 0;  min = 0;
=> 5     max = 5;  min = 0;
=> 15    max = 15; min = 0;
=> 26    max = 26; min = 0;
=> 68    max = 68; min = 0;
```

To get the right results, you should do:

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Comment: thanks. I know that but. if user type -99 and want to close the program without any number input. there is no max and min value. suppose to show no numbers entered or zero.